# HTML - where can I put the <template> tag without the W3C validator complaining?

Tags: html, templates

I've tried every possible combination right now. Theoretically, it can be placed anywhere within the `<body>`, `<head>` and even inside `<table>` or `<select>` elements, but if I place a simple `<template></template>` tag pair without anything else inside, the W3C validator (the tool I base all my HTML5 and CSS3 validation on) gives me the finger.

Can someone give me a rough example of where does the `<template>` tag goes in practical reality? I find no solution (or maybe the W3C validator doesn't validate the `<template>` tag correctly yet, don't know...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<template>` tag currently has the status of an editors draft. That means it is not part of the W3C standard yet, so the W3C validator doesn't recognize it. The [current draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/templates/index.html#introduction) says:

> The `<template>` element can be placed anywhere within the `<head>`,
>   `<body>`, and `<frameset>` elements, and its contents can contain any
>   content which could otherwise occur at any location within the `<head>`,
>   `<body>`, and `<frameset>` elements.

So unless the draft changes in the future, you can place templates wherever you want in your code.

Keep in mind that using features which are still in draft state is dangerous. Before it is an official standard which is supported by all browsers, I would recommend you to use `<div style="display:none">` instead of `<template>`.

Comment: Thanks for the info :). I began suspecting I was playing with material too new for any validator to work with, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: About the replacement suggestion, no. I've built a pure HTML5 framework, so support for in-draft elements allows me to toy with them while they get the recommendation status. So far, I'm just missing the `<template>` tag, everything else is pretty much covered for now :P

Comment: It has been a while since this was posted. Anybody know if templates are now officially supported? I just tried this in VS2012, and it appears that it is not, at least not in my current IDE version).